# background service to send HTTP request and show notifications

Tags: java, android, http

My Android application works without a backend server and it gathers data via HTTP requests to certain websites. I know a way to send those requests from within the app while it is running^ but I would like to send requests as well as when the application is not running because I need to call notifications on the device in response to said requests.

Firebase is not the way I can achieve this goal.

Comment: Please be more descriptive and show us what you've tried so far

Comment: The basic idea is to:
1. Always run a background process or something like that (I know that persistent services are not a good way to do this)
2. In that process send a certain HTTP request
3. In case certain conditions are met upon receiving a response fire a notification on the phone

Answer (score 0):

You can write a class which extends BroadcastReceiver and check whether the Network State is changed. Like this example

```
public class NetworkChangedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (isNetworkAvailable(context)) 
        {
         Toast.makeText(context, "Call your HTTP Request",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        }
    }
}
```